# What does repeat n times mean in gdb debugger?

Tags: c++, gdb

For example:

```
bool plugin::checkQuality(string &text)
{
    
    string temp = normalizeContent(text, 1);
    
    map<string, int> mapWords;
    matchWords(temp.c_str(), mapWords);
    ...
}
```

Once gdb enter this function, I can see the value as:

```
plugin::checkQuality (this=0x7fffffffd9c0, 
    text="This is a test", ' ' <repeats 20 times>, "c,,,,")
    at /mod/filter/plugin.cpp:59
```

What does the 2nd argument <repeats 20 times> means? And what's the 3rd argument "c,,,,"?
Isn't the function only have one argument?

Comment: This seems like gdb's way of saying "twenty spaces go here", and the parameter isjust one string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just the default behavior of how GDB prints more than 10 consecutive identical elements in an array. From the [docs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Print-Settings.html)

> When the number of consecutive identical elements of an array exceeds the threshold, GDB prints the string "<repeats n times>", where n is the number of identical repetitions, instead of displaying the identical elements themselves.

So in your example, the value of the parameter `text` appears to be

```
"This is a test                    c,,,,"
```

You can set the threshold for how many characters need to be repeated before this is printed with

```
set print repeats <number-of-repeats>
```

Comment: So 'c,,,,' is just part of the string.

Comment: @marlon Yes, that's correct.